# How to add a splashscreen to a Flutter webview app?

Tags: ios, flutter, webview

**Hi guys, how can I add a splashscreen to this webview Flutter app.
Because I would like to upload it to App Store.

I uploaded this code to google Store and it has been accepted.
I am very new to flutter and dont have an experince, so please rewrite the code you would tell me to be sure that the answered code is working.

Thank you in advance.

---

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
    import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'My Website',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(
          title: 'My Website',
          url: 'https://www.???.com/'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title, this.url});

  final String title;
  final String url;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  WebViewController _controller;

  final Completer<WebViewController> _controllerCompleter =
      Completer<WebViewController>();
  //Make sure this function return Future<bool> otherwise you will get an error
  Future<bool> _onWillPop(BuildContext context) async {
    if (await _controller.canGoBack()) {
      _controller.goBack();
      return Future.value(false);
    } else {
      return Future.value(true);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => _onWillPop(context),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
            child: WebView(
          key: UniqueKey(),
          onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
            _controllerCompleter.future.then((value) => _controller = value);
            _controllerCompleter.complete(webViewController);
          },
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          initialUrl: widget.url,
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a widget that displays a splash screen and hold the widget for some seconds then push it to your new widget, like this:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'My Website',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(
        title: 'My Website',
        url: 'https://www.google.com/',
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title, this.url});

  final String title;
  final String url;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool loading = true;
  WebViewController _controller;
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controllerCompleter =
      Completer<WebViewController>();
  //Make sure this function return Future<bool> otherwise you will get an error
  Future<bool> _onWillPop(BuildContext context) async {
    if (await _controller.canGoBack()) {
      _controller.goBack();
      return Future.value(false);
    } else {
      return Future.value(true);
    }
  }

  startSplashScreen() async {
    var duration = const Duration(seconds: 3);
    return Timer(
      duration,
      () {
        setState(() {
          loading = false;
        });
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startSplashScreen();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => _onWillPop(context),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: loading == true
            ? Center(
                child: Text(
                 'APP LOGO',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            : SafeArea(
                child: WebView(
                  key: UniqueKey(),
                  initialUrl: widget.url,
                  onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                    _controllerCompleter.complete(webViewController);
                  },
                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                ),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer, but how can I change the APP LOGO to image!

Comment: @MohammadAlkhaled use this `Image.asset("assets/logo/app-logo.png", width: 100, height: 100)` if you wanna use local image and use this `Image.network('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png', height: 100, width: 100)` if you wanna use network image.

Comment: if you find my answer was helpful, can you also vote it up?

Answer (score 0):

use this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/splashscreen)

Add this code before navigating to your homescreen

```
new SplashScreen(
  seconds: 14,
  navigateAfterSeconds: HomeScreen(),
  title: Text('Welcome In SplashScreen'),
  image: Image.asset('splash.png'),
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  photoSize: 100.0,
  loaderColor: Colors.red
);
```

EDIT for example:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'My Website',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: SplashScreen(
      seconds: 5,
      navigateAfterSeconds: MyHomePage(
          title: 'My Website',
          url: 'https://www.???.com/'),
      title: Text('Welcome In SplashScreen'),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      loaderColor: Colors.red
    ),
  );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please copy my code and add your code on it! thank you so much in advancd